# Make one part of a form depend on other part of a form via AJAX

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

In Drupal (7) Form API, it is possible to let one part of a form depend on a single form element, e.g. a select element, via AJAX. This allows to build drilldown forms with unlimited depth.

However, sometimes I would like one part of a form to depend not just on one single select element, but on an entire section of a form, e.g. all elements within a fieldset.

I am going to give some background. But please don't get lost in details.

### Example for simple drilldown

A form with:

- one select element to choose a field.
- another select element to choose a field formatter. This one depends on the former, because different formatters exist for different field types.
- a fieldset to choose the formatter options. Every formatter has different options, so this one would depend on the formatter dropdown via AJAX.

So far this is all doable with Form API, and I already made it work successfully. (If you want, look at renderkit and cfr modules).

### Example for not-so-simple drilldown

This is what this question is about.

A form with

- A select element to choose a type of entity relation. The options are: Entity reference field, taxonomy term reference field, entity author, or "profile2 from user or author".
- In case of one of the two field types, a further select element to choose which field. The options will be all the entityreference fields, or all the taxonomy term reference fields. (entity author does not have any options).
- In case of "profile2 from user or author", there is another select element to choose the profile type.
- There could be other entity-to-entity plugins that would give us other option forms.
- Below all of this, another select element to choose a view mode for displaying the selected entities. This will show view modes for the target entity type of the relationship.

In case of "entityreference field", the target type is only known after choosing the exact field. Maybe for other entity-to-entity plugins, other form elements would define the target type. So the form below (to choose the view mode) would need to be reloaded with AJAX whenever something changes anywhere in the form above. The form would no longer depend on a single element, but on a whole bunch of elements.

I need to stress that the upper part of the form is dynamic and pluggable, so we cannot hardcode targeting any specific elements.

### Ideas so far

One idea was to put the entire upper form into a modal, so that the 
lower part of the form would only reload after the modal is submitted and closed. I think this is more or less what Views is doing.

Another, cheaper idea would be to have one toplevel select element to choose the entity type, and then then have both parts of the form depend on this toplevel select. So e.g. you could only choose entityreference fields where the target type matches the entity type you chose before.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a multi-step form.

Comment: @DavidThomas But does this work with AJAX? So it all happens on one page? I guess I could figure this out myself now.. but if you want to give pointers, go ahead!